# Edge/IE browser leaves font bits on screen from last string after text changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, microsoft-edge

I have a word game that changes the question on screen after each answer, but on some occasion it leaves font traces/bits on screen from the question before that has these letter "roofs" above the font (inside the red circle in the image). I tried to hide/show refresh the elements after each change of sentence but it didn't help.

[image: font bits on screen]

This didn't occur with Chrome or Firefox, only on Edge.

It's taking question from a JS array and changing them with jQuery inside multiple if/else statements (short sample code):

```
<div class="button yes">
<div class="button no">
<div id="question"></div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
questionsArray = [
    'Ты верный <span class="blue">супруг?</span>',
    'До конца <span class="blue">верный?</span>',
    'Любишь ли ты <span class="blue">своих детей?</span>',
    'Нравится ли тебе проводить <span class="blue">время дома?</span>',
    'Нравится ли тебе <span class="blue">забота о детях?</span>',
    'Ты вообще <span class="blue">переносишь детей?</span>',
    'Готов ли ты сам <span class="blue">родить ребенка?</span> ',
    'Готов ли ты <span class="blue">вырастить детей?</span>'
  ]
$('.button.yes').click(function() {
 level++; yes++;
 if(no == 1 && yes == 0) {
  $('#question').html(questionsArray[2])
} else if (yes == 0 && no == 2) {
  $('#question').html(questionsArray[5])
}
});
...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? It looks a bit like you're overlapping all the different questions instead of replacing the prev question with the next one.

Comment: Show some code so we can figure out what you are actually doing that is causing this.

Comment: My bad, i added a short code sample now. does jquery '.html' overlap the previous string and not overwrite the previous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to clear the DIV before adding a new text in it.

Try to use the same DIV for all the questions instead of using new DIV for each questions.

Further, Try to provide a sample code. So that we can try to check it to find the issue in it and try to provide you more accurate suggestion.

Comment: i added "$('#question').html('');" to empty the div before each new question and it did the trick!